# how to learn Java RMI quickly

Tags: java, ipc, rmi

I have a Java application I've been working on for a year or two now. I would like to create a very simple set (with potential to add complexity later) of interfaces that I can use to control my Java app from another JVM (e.g. MATLAB).

I am assuming RMI is the best way to do this, but I'm not sure, as I know next to nothing about it.

**What is the best way to learn RMI quickly?**

Let's say I want to use an interface like this:

```
interface Application {
   public void setLoggingEnabled(boolean enable);
   public boolean isLoggingEnabled();
}
```

How could I implement a bridge between the two JVMs with this interface using RMI? What do I have to know about blocking / threading / synchronization to make this work?

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding callbacks in your first project, that is, keep the communication one way. It's really tempting to have the server be able to initiate communication with the client but once firewalls get introduced things can get pretty hard to manage (especially in strictly controlled environments). Not saying there's anything wrong with callbacks, just saying you should refrain from using them until you get the one-way communication right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good links to start with :

**RMI Guide :**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/

**RMI Tutorial:**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Comment: +1 for RMI guide which includes the spec and a FAQ, I think I've got a good handle on the basics now, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

One quick way to do this is to use Spring. This doesn't (necessarily) mean using lots of XML configuration: Spring's RMI support classes can be used programmatically.

The two key classes are:

- [`RmiServiceExporter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiServiceExporter.html) to make an object remotely accessible.
- [`RmiProxyFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiProxyFactoryBean.html) to access a remote object.

An advantage of doing it this way is that you only need to write an implementation of your interface, and that can then be made available using `RmiServiceExporter`. Meanwhile, on the client side, using `RmiProxyFactoryBean` gives you a proxy object that implements the interface. As far as client-side code is concerned, it's working with a 'real' implementation of the interface, but the proxy does the RMI invocations for you. The use of RMI is transparent.

As an example of how quick this can be, I've just written a server and client using your interface.

My implementation of the interface is:

```
public class ApplicationImpl implements Application {

    private boolean enable;

    @Override
    public void setLoggingEnabled(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggingEnabled() {
        return enable;
    }

}
```

The server-side code is:

```
RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
exporter.setService(new ApplicationImpl());
exporter.setServiceInterface(Application.class);
exporter.setServiceName("application");
exporter.afterPropertiesSet();
```

The client-side code is:

```
RmiProxyFactoryBean pfb = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
pfb.setServiceInterface(Application.class);
pfb.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost/application");
pfb.afterPropertiesSet();
Application app = (Application) pfb.getObject();

System.out.println(app.isLoggingEnabled());
app.setLoggingEnabled(true);
System.out.println(app.isLoggingEnabled());
```

which as expected outputs:

```
false
true
```

Comment: cool, thanks for the details. not sure if I want to use Spring rather than plain RMI (not sure of dependency overhead) but it gives me some ideas.

Answer (score 6):

You can start with the official [RMI tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

---

**Resources :**

- [Introduction to Java RMI](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html)
- [Learn Java RMI](http://www.learn-rmi.thiyagaraaj.com/)

**On the same topic :**

- [Java RMI Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407614/java-rmi-resources)

Comment: Second link broken, probably thankfully. It isn't necessary or advisable to use third-party resources when official documentation is available.

Answer (score 1):

As Yok and Colin said Take a look to the RMI tutorial supported by Oracle (Sun) and by the time you are reading try to code the example codes and test them in an example project.

### References

- RMI Tutorial : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html