# Java RMI Client experienced ClassCastException

Tags: java, rmi, classcastexception

I'm having trouble connecting my RMI client to the server. So I have these classes/interfaces :

```
    package application;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    public interface InterfaceRMI {

        public void insererEtudiant(String requete);
        public void supprimerEtudiant(String requete);
        public ResultSet selectionnerEtudiant(String requete);
    }
```

Server class :

```
    package application;

    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class ServeurMySQL extends UnicastRemoteObject implements InterfaceRMI {

        public int port;

        public ServeurMySQL(int port) throws RemoteException {
            this.port = port;
        }


        @Override
        public void insererEtudiant(String requete) {
           // Implementation for insertion 
        }

        @Override
        public void supprimerEtudiant(String requete) {
          // Implementation for delete
        }

        @Override
        public ResultSet selectionnerEtudiant(String requete) {
            // Implementation for selection  
        }
    }
```

Connection test class :

```
    package application;

    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             try {          
                Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1098);

                InterfaceRMI serveur = (InterfaceRMI) (r.lookup("serveurMySQL"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I replaced the line `InterfaceRMI serveur = (InterfaceRMI) (r.lookup("serveurMySQL"));` by `r.lookup("serveurMySQL");` I didn't get the Exception, I understood that the connection worked, and the problem was only the cast. But I don't know how to resolve it.

The exeption is as follows :

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to application.InterfaceRMI
at application.test.main(test.java:13)
```

P.S: The RMI server is launched without any problem.

Comment: Show us the exception

Comment: you didnt show the code for rmi server

Comment: Hint: try reading some tutorials about this. Do **not** try to learn your way from just looking at javadoc or having *ideas* how those things work. Simply start with a fully described setup that is *known* to work. And: dont put code into comments. update your question instead. Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638024/how-to-learn-java-rmi-quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

```
 public interface InterfaceRMI
```

has to be

```
 public interface InterfaceRMI extends Remote
```

Second:

every method in your `InterfaceRMI` must declare `throws RemoteException`

Comment: I tried it using this extension but then I had another exception while launching the server himself, but thanks I'm gonna try to throw `RemoteException` from interface methods.

Comment: @KhalilHamani When you're given an answer, there's not much point in only trying the bits of it that you like. You have to do it all.